# Google Ad Only Sometimes Flush Left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, adsense

For some reason google decides to place different lengths of ads in this slot.  Sometimes it is shorter and sometimes longer.  As a result, for some reason the shorter ads don't show flush left.

[image]

[image]

The containing div has nothing special in it and it's a responsive ad:

```
                <div class="margin-bottom-10">
                    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

                    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                         style="display:block"
                         data-ad-client="xxxxxx"
                         data-ad-slot="xxxxx"
                         data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
                    <script>
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                    </script>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this CSS and check out

```
.margin-bottom-10{text-align:left}
```